# Displaying Post Attachment(s) at Top of single.php

Tags: attachments, customization

I'm using the latest build of WP and would like to display the first image attached to the post at the top of the post content. What code do I have to add to single.php to make this happen?

Comment: I assume you've already considered using the Featured Image and decided it doesn't meet your use case? (Are these a large number of existing posts, or are you designing a system for posts to be added in the future?)

Comment: Not really. Thanks for the heads up. Researching it now > http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments are considered children of the post they're attached to, so this should work:

```
$images=get_children( array('post_parent'=>$post->ID,
                            'post_mime_type'=>'image',
                             'numberposts'=>1));
echo wp_get_attachment_image($images[0]->ID, 'large');
```

for a large image... replace "large" with the size definition you want or a width,height array.

Comment: Thanks goldenapples. I'm assuming your numberposts parameter takes care of just loading the first image (by image order in the sort options of the gallery)

Comment: Yeah, numberposts=1 only loads one attachment, and I left the sort order as the default. It still returns an array, however, which is why the next line still has to refer to $images[0].

Answer (score 1):

**Function to get first image attached to a post**

```
function the_image($size = 'medium' , $class = ”){
global $post;

//setup the attachment array
$att_array = array(
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'order_by' => 'menu_order'
);

//get the post attachments
$attachments = get_children($att_array);

//make sure there are attachments
if (is_array($attachments)){
//loop through them
foreach($attachments as $att){
//find the one we want based on its characteristics
if ( $att->menu_order == 0){
$image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att->ID, $size);

//get url – 1 and 2 are the x and y dimensions
$url = $image_src_array[0];
$caption = $att->post_excerpt;
$image_html = '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />';

//combine the data
$html = sprintf($image_html,$url,$caption,$class);

//echo the result
echo $html;
}
}
}
}
```

***Now we need to tell WordPress where to display this image***

Add this line where you want to display the image:

```
<?php the_image('medium','post-image'); ?>
```

***The Gotcha for using this aproach***

If you add an image to the post editor it will display 2 times.

***A case for using this approach***

This works great when you want to use thumbnails(featured image) on your blog pages then display a larger version of the image in single.php and don't want to have to set a featured image then manually insert it.  With this method you just set the featured image to attach it to the post and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to limit it to the first attachment (and how to limit it to image attachments), but this should be a good starting point.  From [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post):

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
    ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
    }
}

?>
```